# CreateTabBottomNavigator and swipe gestures. Swipe working very slow,why?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-tabnavigator

I have a problem which I couldn't fix.

I have an "`createBottomTabNavigator`" with 3 pages.

On one page I have a `ListView` which gets the data from `AsyncStorage`. My intention is, that I can delete a row( which works fine) and edit a row( which also works fine).
My problem is that the buttons "delete" & "edit" will be shown with a left/right swipe on the row.
This swipe works but is really really bad and slow.

I use a 3rd party component called "react-native-swipe-list-view". I also tested 3 other components and they all worked really bad.

Is there may be a chance that the problem is the `bottomTabNavigator`? Is there a way that the Navigator has a swipe function and that's the reason why everything lacks?

Maybe someone has the same problem and has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `BottomNavigation` with `ViewPager` its works finely..

otherwise you can use `Tablayout` with `ViewPager` and set the `Bottom` side...

both option can fulfill your Requirement ... and swipe regularly..smooth...

Comment: ok try and tell me its works or not ... coz i m trying that can works so... any problem face with your code then then tell me ... i can  help for issues